# "Routing Error uninitialized constant" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've gone through a number of the causes of this problem but I think that this issue is related to the names I've given my resources. Here's the command I'm running.

`rails generate scaffold_controller iform__c content__c:String header__c:String`

But when I navigate to:

```
http://localhost:3000/iform__cs
```

I get the following error:

```
Routing Error

uninitialized constant Iform_csController
```

I've raked the DB, the files all exist so I'm very confused. I've tried exactly the same `rails g` command for a resource named "account" and it seems to work perfectly.

Would love to know if anyone can explain why I'm getting this error.

Comment: You've build controller for 'iform__c' but asking for controller 'iform__cs', is it typo?

Comment: Why are you using the `__c` prefix? It's quite disgusting.

Comment: The 's' on the end is the pluralisation. The `__c` is vomit-worthy but is a requirement due to the system I'm integrating with and an underlying integration library. Makes me unhappy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails uses a bunch of conventions to make things work smoothly. You're breaking pretty much every single one with this naming scheme.

If it's a legacy database you're having to deal with, I suggest using [updateable VIEWs](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Updatable_views) to bring the column and table names in line with Rails' expectations.

If it's a legacy URL scheme you're having to deal with, consider creating a clean structure within Rails, and rewrite legacy URLs to the new-style ones with [nginx rewrite rules](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule).

(If you're unwilling to do either, Rails may not be the software for you. [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/) may provide you with the capability to service tangled Enterprise application structures more easily.)

Comment: I think these are great tips. The updateable VIEWs is probably the way I need to go. Thanks!